# RC filters in JFET negative feedback

Tags: filter, active-filter, jfet, band-pass, negative-feedback

[image]

I saw a useful answer about JEFT negative feedback here and so I thought I'd ask for some help too!!

I'm attempting to create a JFET gain stage that uses a filter in a negative feedback loop to boost a frequency range, in the same way you would do with an op amp or inverter gain stage.

Here is the basic schematic. Even if I adjust R4 to increase the gain from the stage I don't see the same frequency response from the filter that I would if I used it as a filter or in a feedback loop of an op amp. I tend to just get variations of mid to high frequency roll of, rather than the notch response I'd expect from the filter.

Comment: The short answer is that you appear to not be taking into account the fact that the amplifier loads the feedback network, and visa-versa (you don't need to do this as much with op-amps).  The long answer is -- long, and if someone gets to it before me, more power to them!

Answer (score 0):

JFET filter can be used with varying your C9 and C10.

Here's what happens ... with "no load" ...

[image]